# Field acting like there's a phantom offset column to its left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap so I'm sorry if I missed anything obvious.

Please have a look at this:
http://www.bootply.com/mF2S5AcG3G

Can anyone explain why Field 3 is acting like there's an "offset" column to its left?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? [An inline form?](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

Answer (score 0):

This is a passage from [grid-introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro):

Predefined grid classes like .row and .col-xs-4 are available for quickly making        grid layouts. Less mixins can also be used for more semantic layouts.

Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

The negative margin is why the examples below are outdented. It's so that content within grid columns is lined up with non-grid content.

you may have to add this :

```
<div class="row">
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to let the fields simply "go with the flow" and fit in one next to the other, and not have to hard-wrap columns in a "row".